# When loading an array of photos, how can I make a unique comment button function for each imageID?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

1. Page loads with reference to commentIMage.js, and comment.php
2. User enters comment and clicks button, references from commentImage.js
3. comentImage.js ($comment).click(function{..}) doesn't load

**html**

```
<textarea required=required name ="comment" id="comment"></textarea><br/>
              <input type="hidden" id="image" name ="image" value="<?php echo $images[$i]['imageID']?>" />
              <input type=button id=postComment value="Post Comment">
```

**commentImage.js**
    $(document).ready(function(){

```
    $('#postComment').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'commentImage.php',
            data:{newComment:$('#comment').val(), postID:postID},
            success:function(data){
                var data = JSON.parse(data);
                var comment = makeComment(data['user'], $('#comment').val(), data['date']);
                $('#commentsBock').prepend(comment);
                $('#comment').val('');
            }
        })
    })
})

function makeComment(user, comment, date){
    var comment = '<div><div>'+user+'</div><div>'+comment+'</div><div>'+date+'</div><div>';
    return comment;
}
function getComments(){

}
```

**commentImage.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_POST['comment'];
echo $_POST['image'];
include_once('mysql.php');
...
?>
```

Comment: `echo $_POST['comment'];echo $_POST['image'];` is already invalid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#comment` is a unique ID. If you use it more than one time in your HTML, don't wait for it to work properly, it won't !

Just use your PostID like `id="comment_"+PostID` to create unique identifiers.
And use `$("input[id^='comment_']")` to select all IDs which id start with `comment_` *(that's what `^=` does)*

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2b6cLkd/3/)

Comment: THis solution actually doesnt worK
$("#postComment[id^='postComment_']").click(function(){
        console.log("clicked");
        $.ajax({

<input type=button id="postComment_<?php echo $images[$i]['imageID']?>" value="Post comment">

Comment: Updated the answer, I did a mistake in my code .. 
Also added a JSFiddle !